# How to solve duplicate request with Distributed Lock Management in Golang

Tags: golang

I’m trying to test concurrently request (brute force test), with 1000 request/sec (same request id). I’m using Rest API.

The service running on distributed system, I’m using 3 pods.

The problem is I got duplication when inserting data, because we use distributed 3 pods consume concurrently (the request).

Then I tried some method to handle duplication:

1. Using `sync.Mutex` still got duplicate because each pods has process different var sync.Mutex . So it’s not lock each pods.
2. Using `singleflight` it’s work on 1 pods, but when run on distributed pods, it still duplicate, because different var singleflight also.
3. Using `Redis Lock` DLM (Distributed Lock Management). It’s work on 1 pods, but when distributed, it’s still duplicate also.

The one that I’ve not yet implemented is using Message Queue .

Before I try that, is there any simple method to handle duplication from distributed system ?

Comment: What are you inserting the data to? The usual answer to distributed locks is redesign not to need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know i'm late to the party, but to anyone interested, there is a distributed redis lock https://github.com/go-redsync/redsync . It doesn't follow Lock interface strictly, but it should be easy to implement.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/255193)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).